# Need to check ON or OFF state of a wire using non-invasive method

Tags: voltage-divider, electricity, current-sensor, non-contact

We have a GSM SMS alert system (mod bus) that needs a signal that a wire (any wire from 3-phase) has current (maximum 15 amperes in ON state) or not, so we can know if the system is  ON or OFF.

There are non-invasive CT products but need guidance on how to use it so that we get signal +5V or 0V to differentiate ON or OFF.

*problem statement* : we want to know if the appliance connected to the main power is tripped or not remotely (SMS alert device), for this purpose the current in the live wire drops to ~0amps when the appliance is tripped, and when its working the current is ~15 amps, we need a non-invasive clamp on one of the 3-wires, not all 3 as it would give zero reading, so that make a simple circuit to get input to SMS device (5V-on, 0V-off) signal

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcOdyL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: CT is an abbreviation of Current Transformer, while there exist also voltage detector circuits similar to voltage tester which detects voltage presence, while CT would detect the current. You should clarify if you need to detect voltage or device current.

Answer (score 0):

A *current transformer* senses AC current through one winding, and flux-transfers current to its other winding: that's conventional transformer action. To confine the flux, some high-permeability material is often used.

The primary winding is usually one, single turn (green in the photo below). It doesn't look like a turn, because the wire you're trying to sense simply passes through the centre of the transformer once. This would be "anyone wire of three-phase":

[image: magnelab uct-0300-020 current transformer]
*from:Magnelab UCT-0300-020 Solid Core Current Transformer*

The secondary winding having many turns is potted around the core. In the photo, it exits the transformer as twisted white-black wires. This winding is terminated in a resistor. Voltage across this resistor is AC, whose amplitude and phase is proportional to current flowing in the primary winding.
Average voltage across the resistor is zero. With no primary current flowing, AC voltage across the resistor is zero.

For your application, some electronics is required to detect when the secondary winding AC voltage exceeds a desired voltage, perhaps in separate stages:

- convert AC-to-DC
- detect when DC voltage exceeds a threshold DC voltage set by you
- convert to logic level: 0V or +5V

Answer (score 0):

> ...  a signal that a wire (anyone wire from 3-phase) is having current ... or no, so we can know that system is OFF or ON state

I suspect that you want to check whether the cables are **live** or not. Cables can be live even if no current is flowing (if the switch at the load end of the cable is off, for example).

> ... anyone wire from 3-phase ...

Measuring current on all three phases together should always give a zero reading as whatever goes out on one wire must come back on the other two. The resultant reading of a current meter clamped around the three cables will be 0 A.

Please edit your question to clarify what your requirements are. Better again, state what the real problem is rather than how you think you should solve it.

Comment: _problem statement_ : we want to know if the appliance connected to the main power is tripped or not remotely (SMS alert device), for this purpose the current in the live wire drops to ~0amps when the appliance is tripped, and when its working the current is ~15 amps, we need a non-invasive clamp on one of the 3-wires, not all 3 as it would give zero reading, so that make a simple circuit to get input to SMS device (5V-on, 0V-off) signal